# how to remove /?fbclid=... in nuxt url

Tags: javascript, facebook, vue.js, nuxt.js

hello there i like to remove the facebook analytic forced url parameter `/?fbclid=` `https://www.example.com/?fbclid=...`, from my host url, when redirected from facebook by clicking the url, the problem is the nuxt-link-exact-active class is not applied if redirected with this parameter.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In simple cases like  `https://www.example.com/?fbclid=...` where **fbclid** is the only parameter, it should be a trivial Javascript like that:

```
 <script>
  // ideally this is on top of page; works on bottom as well

  if(/^\?fbclid=/.test(location.search))
     location.replace(location.href.replace(/\?fbclid.+/, ""));

 </script>
```

This checks if `?fbclid=...` is a URL search parameter and navigates to the same location with that part removed.

---

It may also be fine to remove any search parameter and not checking for `fbclid`.

```
 <script>
   if(location.search) location.replace(location.href.replace(/\?.+/, ""));
 </script>
```

Comment: and is `fbclid` *ISNT* the only parameter, the RegExp would be `/[\?&]fbclid=[^&]+/` https://regexr.com/6j2s0

Answer (score 4):

For simple cases like `https://www.example.com/?fbclid=...` where **fbclid** is the first and only parameter, it can be done by a simple server configuration.

So for example put this in the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
<if "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /^fbclid=/">
 RewriteRule  .  %{REQUEST_URI}?   [R=301,L]
</if>
```

Note the `?` after `%{REQUEST_URI}`. It deletes the query string completely.

---

In other cases (where **fbclid** was appended to other parameters) this example does nothing - more complicated code is needed for that.

Comment: top answer great man!

Answer (score 1):

i could finally solved it with this:

```
methods: {
  removeFacebookHook() {
    var fbParam = 'fbclid';

    // Check if param exists
    if (location.search.indexOf(fbParam + '=') !== -1) {
      var replace = '';

      try {
        var url = new URL(location);
        url.searchParams.delete(fbParam);
        replace = url.href;

        // Check if locale exists
        if (window.location.href.indexOf(this.locale) > -1) {
          window.history.replaceState(null, null, "/" + this.locale);
        };

      } catch (ex) {
        var regExp = new RegExp('[?&]' + fbParam + '=.*$');
        replace = location.search.replace(regExp, '');
        replace = location.pathname + replace + location.hash;
      }

      history.replaceState(null, '', replace);
    }
  }
}
```

with the help of this post [modiyf urls](https://www.michalspacek.com/using-javascript-to-modify-urls-and-hide-fbclid)
I keep the nuxt-i18n route locale working with href.indexOf !
Unfortunately the nuxt alwaysRedirect made me remove the switcher...

Answer (score 1):

I solve the Facebook Query string in a very simple way using JavaScript...
inclue this script in your Layout page or MastrPage

```
  //facebook Route Script for Query string
   function faceBookQuery() {
       addEventListener('fetch', event => {
           let url = new URL(event.request.url)

           if (url.searchParams.has('fbclid'))
               url.searchParams.delete('fbclid')

           event.respondWith(
               fetch(url, event.request)
           );
       });
    }
```

Injoy

Answer (score 1):

Il there is a `#section` like in`https://www.example.com/file?fbclid=...#section` (pervers facebook...) then code proposed by j.j. gives `https://www.example.com/file`.
Better code is

```
if(/^\?fbclid=/.test(location.search))
  location.replace(location.href.replace(location.search, ""));
```

N.B. Removing any search parameter and not checking for fbclid will prevents passing variables via the url...

Thanks to j.j. for showing the way.